# .VBS // 800a01c2 wrong number of arguments "objshell.Run"

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I want to search a .bat file on my USB drive and run it, the problem comes when I try to execute and give me this error:

ERROR in line 16, char 1 800a01c2 wrong number of arguments "objshell.Run"

This is my code:

```
Set objshell = WSH.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = WSH.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set drives = fso.Drives

For Each drive in drives
    batfile = drive.DriveLetter & ":\ZEC\NVIDIA\InstallerSin.bat"
    if fso.FileExists(batfile) Then Exit For
Next

If not fso.FileExists(batfile) Then
    WSH.Echo("bat script not found.")
    WSH.Quit(1)
End If

WSH.Echo("found it: " & batfile)
objshell.Run batfile, 0, True, vbhide
```

Comment: You need to explain what you want to achieve with the code instead of expecting people figure that out by reading the code

Comment: Sorry is my first post and Im a little bit lost, I want to search a .bat file on my USB drive and run it, I edit the post

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [Ask] and [MCVE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`objshell.Run` takes at most, three parameters.  You are calling it with four.

https://ss64.com/vb/run.html
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156605.aspx

Comment: Down votes without comments seem rather capricious.  Was there a reason for it?